# Hola ¿Cómo puedo ingresar un sudoku por teclado a una matriz en java?

Tags: java, matriz

Tengo una duda acerca de como ingresar datos por teclado hacia una matriz. La entrada sería un Sudoku el cual sería ingresado por consola de la siguiente forma:

```
0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

¿Cómo ingreso esto en una matriz[9][9]? Cada casilla es separada por un espacio y cada línea por un "enter". Si pueden explicarme sería de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que quiero un tablero de 5x5 (igual vos le agregas el tamaño que quieras):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main { 
 
  public static void main (String[] args){

  int [][] tablero =  new int[5][5]; // declaramos array bidimensional
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // lector del teclado

  for(int i=0;i<tablero.length;i++){ // recorremos una dimension
    for(int j=0;j<tablero[0].length;j++){ // recorremos la otra
      tablero[i][j] = scanner.nextInt(); // leemos el elemento
    }
  }
  
  for(int i=0;i<tablero.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<tablero[0].length;j++){
      System.out.print(" " + tablero[i][j]); // imprimimos con un espacio de por medio
    }
    System.out.println(); // esto es un salto de linea
  }

  scanner.close(); // cerramos lector
}

}
```